# Can't open PDF file located in server in WebView on android device

Tags: android-webview

I would like to open a PDF file that located in the server ([Here](http://mes.mes-ltd.com/itay.pdf))

in a specific place in my application.

I saw a couple of example how to do it with a webview, but no one works for me.

This is part of my code that should preview the pdf inside a WebView :

```
     WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
     webView.getSettings().setSaveFormData(true);
     webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
     webView.loadUrl("http://mes.mes-ltd.com/itay.pdf");
```

The solution is just a Blank webview.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

You can't open a PDF directly in the WebView, it just doesn't support this. You'll need to do something like the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20603855/2977376) outlined here.

Comment: I did this, But if i want to show the pdf file not in a new intent? and only in a part of the screen. what should i do?

Comment: @user2235615 - you'd probably need to embed some sort of pdf viewer in your app then. See https://code.google.com/p/apv/ for example.