# Android - any recent change in permissions handling? Shortly I get fileNotFound (permission denied) errors

Tags: android, android-permissions

My Android app runs for years on mobiles with Android 7 and 8. At the start all permissions are requested and granted. This works for years.

Since a few days (end May 2019) I get this error on different mobiles:

W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/WPE_log.txt (Permission denied). The same on /storage/emulated/0/Download/WPE/filenames.

All permissions were granted (a year) ago.

Have there been any recent changes that have effect on the permissions system?

Comment: Check this example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55816746/filedownloader-at-the-android-it-is-showing-no-errors-but-the-download-does-not/56313094#56313094 There are changes to API 28 Android Permissions

Comment: Thank you. Yeah, saw the page. In this case it is about accessing storage. I guess nothing changed for those priviliges / permissions since Android 6+: READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE. I asked en got the right permissions since a year+. Why do I get errors since a few days at difference mobiles?

Comment: Hi @tjm1706 there are updates pushed from google to the devices which is breaking. I am also having multiple issues, check your code in the latest version of Android Emulator to see if you can replicate.

Comment: Thank you! I will do. Please mark it as an answer. Even when I use API 27 there are problems?